# Neo4j performance in server mode

Tags: neo4j

I am learning neo4j. I am accessing neo4j via REST api(s) supported by the server mode. CRUD operations are implemented using neo4jOperations. For experimentation , I have benchmarked its read operations but I have found that methods : 'query' and 'queryForObjects' are taking huge execution time, although I am querying via a field which is indexed. Traversals are not complex. 
I have : around 500K+ nodes, 900K+ relationships. 
neo4j version : 3.0.8.

Is there any solution to improve the performance of query on neo4j in server mode?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your actual queries and model it is hard to say why the performance would not be up to your expectations. Try to run the queries through the Neo4j browser and either **EXPLAIN** or **PROFILE** them, that may give you a hint of where the issue is.

Having said that, you really should move to version 3.2.1 and access the server over the bolt:/ protocol. That by itself should already significantly improve things.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Hi Tom,
I am also using spatial index on one of the node property. Is spatial index supported in neo4j - 3.2.1 ? As earlier, I have faced some issues in creating spatial index in this version. Sample query via REST api :

http://localhost:7474
{"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH (n:`Location`) WHERE n.`id` IN {`id`} return n","parameters":{"id":["1","2"]},"resultDataContents":["rest"],"includeStats":true}]}
Query on neo4j shell : MATCH (n:`Location`) WHERE n.`id` IN ['1','2'] return n;
id is indexed.

Comment: Interesting. Can you do the same in the browser with PROFILE in front of the MATCH ? It should show two index-hits right at the top. What response time are you getting for this query ?

The spatial index plugin definitely works on 3.1.2. I haven't tried it yet on 3.2.1 (as I'm personally not into spatial indexing) but it should work.